# What is the correct mathematical symbolism for expressing how many times I have to subtract a variable number from a given starting point?

Tags: algorithms

Say that I have 1000 dollars that I need to collect. I know that on the first day my income is 20 dollars, one the second it's 30 dollars and so on, on every subsequent day my income increases by 10 dollars. I also know that on every day I save 80% of my income. How would I express calculating how many days it takes until I have 1000 dollars saved?

The operation would be: ((((1000 - 20 * 0.8) - 30 * 0.8) - 40 * 0.8) - 50 * 0.8) ....
And I would like to count how many times I have to do this subtraction before I reach 0.

I know how I would do this algorithmically/programmatically, just making a loop that adds to some counter every time it runs and stops when it gets to 0, but I'm not sure how to express this as a mathematical equation. What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compute

$$0.8 \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \left(20+10i\right)\right)=8 \left(2n+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\right)$$

and then equate to $1000$. Therefore, you have to solve

$$1000=8 \left(2n+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\right)$$

I get $n=\frac{5}{2}\left(\sqrt{41}-1\right)\approx 13.5.$

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Would you mind explaining shortly how you got from the sum to the expression without the sum in your first equation?

Comment: $$\begin{split}0.8 \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \left(20+10i\right)\right)&=0.8 \left(\sum_{i=0}^n 20+\sum_{i=1}^n 10i\right)\\&=0.8 \left(20\sum_{i=0}^n 1+10\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)\\&=8\left(2\sum_{i=0}^n 1+\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)\end{split}$$ The first sum in the last equality is just $n$ and the second is the sum of the first $n$ naturals, that add up to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: @Rico If this solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark